# Merge two pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I want to concat two multindex columns:

```
a = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ ["vowels"], ["a","e"] ])
b = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [ ["consonants"], ["b","c",] ] )
a + b 
   MultiIndex([('vowels', 'a'),
              ('vowels', 'e'),
              ('consonants', 'b'),
              ('consonants', 'c')],
             )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.append.html):

```
c = a.append(b)
print (c)
MultiIndex([(    'vowels', 'a'),
            (    'vowels', 'e'),
            ('consonants', 'b'),
            ('consonants', 'c')],
           )
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
out = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([*a,*b])

MultiIndex([(    'vowels', 'a'),
            (    'vowels', 'e'),
            ('consonants', 'b'),
            ('consonants', 'c')],
           )
```